# Why is Ionic animation so smooth?

Tags: javascript, cordova, animation, ionic-framework, velocity.js

I am using ionic to develop my hybrid mobile app project. Now, I am trying to apply some custom animation into my app element. From my research, I found that velocity.js is one of the fastest performance js animation. So, I try to apply it on a very simple div with only 2 line of text. It animate smoothly on PC. But when I put it into the low end smartphone, it animate very "choppy". When compare to ionic sidemenu animation, Ionic animation runs extremely smooth.

How could Ionic animation run so smooth? How does it achieve it? Is there anyway we can utilize Ionic animation on our custom element? Or, is there any better animation solution than velocity.js?

Comment: Try turning on hardware acceleration.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 How?

Answer (score 0):

I do not use ionic, but I imagine they have a javascript call to do this.

Otherwise, google: [css turn on hardware acceleration](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+turn+on+hardware+acceleration).

This article is likely the best: *HTML5 Rocks* [High Performance Animations](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)
This is good too: *Phonegap Tips* [Force Hardware Acceleration with translate3d... Sometimes](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/force-hardware-acceleration-with-translate3d-sometimes.html)